# convert integer into encrypted string and vice versa

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pass pid as querystring parameter in URL, but instead of int like ?pid=102 or ?pid=493 , I want to pass these pid in encrypted form like ?pid=D109150A13F0EA4 or other encrypted string. I tried  build-in Encrypt method but they give long length string  like
?pid=F3D165BAF8D84FB17CF8E5B4A04AC9022BFF5F987A6EDC42D109150A13F0EA4D847527287C8013154E2E8A2D8DAB6B686751C079092713C0DDA3E2E932D5892361E1B486FE2F46C2E288EA54F64B8B4C

I want small alpha numeric string like ?pid=D109150A13F0EA4 or similar

Comment: What's the goal of encrypting the ID value? What exactly do you want to protect?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Guid`?

```
var g = Guid.NewGuid(productId.ToString());
```

It will produce a result of 38 characters: 8 hexadecimal digits, followed by three groups of 4 hexadecimal digits each, followed by one group of 12 hexadecimal digits.

An example of a Guid: `6B29FC40-CA47-1067-B31D-00DD010662DA`

So it is in fact quite short in comparison with your example. The only drawback of the Guid is that you cannot decrypt it back to int (but you can compare whether two Guids represent the same int value).

In case you need both encryption and decryption, apart from the inbuilt encrypting (I assume you have used the `Encrypt` method in your above example), there are many additional encryption algorithms available in `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace, like:

- [DES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.des%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)       , example: 2120357ccd3e0142
- [Aes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)       , example: 73054ef012f6ea6d47757a37a84381f7
- [HMACSHA256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), example: 6723ace2ec7b0348e1270ccbaab802bfa5c1bbdddd108aece88c739051a8a767

Comment: pid is product id come from db, how to encrypt or decrypt it using Guid.NewGuid() ?

Comment: then how he can decrypt that guid ?

Answer (score 0):

For those things I use a small EncryptDecrypt Class, maybe this help for your approach.

Simle usage like `EncryptDecrypt.ToEncrypt(yourstring)` and `EncryptDecrypt.ToDecrypt(yourEncryptedString)`. So you should be able to encrypt before add to your querystring. Integer and numbers, etc. you have to convert to string first then.

Hope this helps.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace YourNameSpace

{
    public class EncryptDecrypt
    {
        #region Declaration

        static readonly byte[] TripleDesKey1 = new byte[] { 15, 11, 7, 21, 34, 32, 33, 5, 23, 13, 23, 41, 43, 41, 7, 19, 91, 91, 47, 7, 37, 13, 19, 41 };
        static readonly byte[] TripleDesiv1 = new byte[] { 5, 23, 13, 23, 41, 43, 41, 7 };

        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// To Encrypt String
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">String To Encrypt</param>
        /// <returns>Returns Encrypted String</returns>
        public static string ToEncrypt(string value)
        {
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
                                                     {
                                                         Key = TripleDesKey1,
                                                         IV = TripleDesiv1
                                                     };

            MemoryStream ms;

            if (value.Length >= 1)
                ms = new MemoryStream(((value.Length * 2) - 1));
            else
                ms = new MemoryStream();

            ms.Position = 0;
            CryptoStream encStream = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            byte[] plainBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
            encStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
            encStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            encStream.Close();

            return Convert.ToBase64String(plainBytes);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// To Decrypt Data Encrypted From TripleDEC Algoritham
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">String Value To Decrypt</param>
        /// <returns>Return Decrypted Data</returns>
        public static string ToDecrypt(string value)
        {
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            //System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(((value.Length * 2) - 1));
            MemoryStream ms;
            if (value.Length >= 1)
                ms = new MemoryStream(((value.Length * 2) - 1));
            else
                ms = new MemoryStream();

            ms.Position = 0;
            CryptoStream encStream = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(TripleDesKey1, TripleDesiv1), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            byte[] plainBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
            encStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainBytes);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your ToDecrypt method does not release used resources correctly!

Answer (score 0):

This method is used to generate a random string

```
private string GetRandomString(int iStringLength)
    {
        string allowedChars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@$?_-";
        char[] chars = new char[iStringLength];           
            Random rd = new Random();    
            for (int i = 0; i < iStringLength; i++)
            {
                chars[i] = allowedChars[rd.Next(0, allowedChars.Length)];
            }       
            return new string(chars);           
    }
```

or use

```
var gid = Guid.NewGuid(productId.ToString());
```

Below method encrypts a string. just pass a normal/ random string to encrypt the string.

```
 protected string EncryptString(String strString)
    {            
            UnicodeEncoding uEncode = new UnicodeEncoding();
            Byte[] bytstrString = uEncode.GetBytes(strString);
            SHA256Managed sha1 = new SHA256Managed();
            Byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(bytstrString);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

    }
```